# Margins Facebook Like Button

Tags: html, css, facebook, margins

on some websites I am using the Facebook like button, since yesterday there is now a huge margin on the left and right side of the like button. I tried everything but can't get rid of these margins. Now it is messing up other stuff on my websites because the margins are too big.

I made a jsfiddle and made the margins red. How do I get rid of these margins on both sides?

I hope I did everything correct since this is my first post.

Thank you:)

https://jsfiddle.net/oc39Lxg8/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fb-like {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>fb bttn test</title>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_EN/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v5.0"></script>

  </head>

<body>

  button is not comming up here, but it is in my js fiddle, please take a look there https://jsfiddle.net/oc39Lxg8/
  
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://jsfiddle.net/" data-width="" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-share="false"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your icon not showing here?

Comment: is my icon not showing on my jsfiddle? I can see it here: [link](https://i.imgur.com/3zkWEwk.png)

Comment: Yea, I'm also seeing the same issue for my websites. Very annoying issue. I think this is a bug on facebook's end. If you go to facebook's like button generator page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) and use the "iframe" option as opposed to the "javascript sdk" option, no extra left and right margins show up on the like button. So this difference in margins between the 2 options seems to suggest that facebook has messed up here. However, there are other spacing issues though with the iframe option, so that's not ideal either.

Comment: Additionally, I just noticed that if you click the empty margin space either to the left or right of the like button, that actually registers a click on the actual like button. So this definitely seems to suggest that this is a bug on facebook's end. I hope they fix this quickly. Not sure there is much we can do as the like button is inside an iframe so we cannot apply css onto it ourselves to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, guess we have to wait till Monday when the Facebook-office opens

Answer (score 2):

Having a look at Facebook's support page, there has been a bug reported about this issue.  You can follow its progress here [huge margins around the like button](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1194214784101513/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all properties of div and just keep class property

```
<div class="fb-like"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Digging through the fb connect script, it seemed they changed the width to 225px fixed. Wondering why, considering the simple like button is less than 225px, using unnecessary space on a page while causing visitors to "like" without realizing they actually clicked on it. Must be a silly bug.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook solved the issue!:) Thanks